# Search Uploaded Media in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to do this? I've tried a couple different search plugins and none seem to do it. I want the search to return media assets based on their description\alt text.

Answer (score 0):

this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Media_Library_SubPanel has all the answer you need.
but you can click the `media` tab and click `library` and search in the top right.

good luck

Comment: I want users to be able to search, not admins.